# upgrade to a 200 amp service, cable wiring sizes

Tags: electrical, wiring, breaker-box

The house currently has a 3/4 inch conduit to feed the main wires coming from the power company to the breaker box. This is very much inadequate. I plan to upgrade to a much bigger breaker box. 
My question is what size wire should i use from the meter to the breaker box. There is no NEC or any kind of regulation here and SE wire doesnt exist here so ill just run separate wires through a new conduit.

Comment: Where is here?? Everyone has to follow some sort of codes. Even if it's just your utility's requirements.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- some places are backwards/crazy enough to not have any sort of electrical code, although I'd be astonished if his utility didn't have requirements on services.

Comment: Ecuador. There arent any requirements of any kind as long as you dont break the meter.

Comment: Unless you know that the utility service is identical to the US (or another country), I think you should just talk to the utility company about how many conductors and what size. Even if there aren't formal building codes there will be local standards.

Comment: i assure you there are no local standards. you walk down a street and you see the meters all over the place with different amp sizes for no reason, the wiring is done with plastic tape rarely do you see wire nuts. I assure you there isnt anything. So im trying to go by american standards as much as possible. Even today people steal electricity from the high tension wires. They just hook up light bulbs and stuff to it. Or they run gigantic thin extension cords across entire streets.

Comment: @Learner: I really think you need to find someone who is familiar with the electrical supply in Ecuador, and apparently there isn't anyone on this site. It's not just a question of US standards being "better" or more stringent... the electric grid may be different. E.g. in the US, residential power is supplied from the meter with 3 wires: two hots and a neutral. Ground is provided by grounding rods installed at the building, not from the utility. But maybe Ecuador is different? Many countries only use 1 hot wire, not 2. And ground might be different?

Comment: Well we are changing everything right now. We do more or less follow american guidelines to an extent. We do have two hot thats part of the problem the government is now forcing homes to get to 22O for induction stoves. Theyre arent any rods anywhere. Id have to install them myself which is fine. Though today i saw the utility man who explained how to steal electricity from the company and do it in a way no one will catch on.

Comment: For what it's worth, reducing your usage of electricity is another alternatine. Since moving to CFLs and LEDs, and newer PC's, I doubt I'm using anything close to my 100A service. Newer fridge and clothes drier (probably gas for the lstter) will further reduce demand, when their time comes.

Answer (score 1):

For a 200A residential service in the US or Cananda typical would be 4/0-4/0-2/0AL or 2/0-2/0-1/0CU conductors. Either combination would normally be run in 2" conduit.

This is only scratching the surface of what you need to know to do this project. Are you aware and knowledgeable of all the other requirements/codes/etc???

Comment: Does this assume 120/240V single split-phase service, or would this hold true for three phase or 230V 50hz single phase as well?

Comment: Does that mean i could buy three separate wires two 2/O and one 1/O. If i wanted to add grounding would i need to run the ground wire out to the meter? Would that still fit in the 2 inch conduit.

Comment: @Tester101, I think you know this applies to single-phase 120/240V services since this is a "Home Improvement" forum like it says at the top of the page. And since the original poster says there is no "NEC" or other codes one could have safely assumed he was in the US. I guess that was an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Seeing as the question is not about a US installation I will refrain from replying further. My answer still stands with regard to a US or Canadian installation.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I was asking because I thought the OP might *not* live in the US.

Comment: IMO putting your location in the question should be mandatory to avoid mix ups like this. The VAST majority of questions come from North America so when it is not very obvious by the verbiage of the question it can get confusing.

Comment: In this case i just want to try and follow north american rules with the materials i have at my disposal here.

Comment: would it be prudent to run a ground wire back out from the panel to the meter. My plumbing is all PVC

Comment: No, this is not necessary or wanted. That bond exists through the service neutral. You do not want another path.

Comment: so as long as the ground wire is connected to the neutral wire at the breaker box its fine? i should run ground to a rod shouldnt i though?